# Application Architecture : servers and layers

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, architecture, glassfish

I want to know what is the difference between an application server and a web server and what is the classification of glassfish and Tomcat (application server or a web server) .
In wich kind of server we can find servlet and JSP.
Any ideas please , and if you can give me a list of ebooks or links about application architecture : (layers...)how to make it and how to choose the best one for your application .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat is a Java EE server which doesn't support the full Java EE stack. It concentrates on webapp support (servlets and JSPs), provides a JDBC connection pool and JNDI support, but doesn't have EJBs and JMS for example.

GlassFish is a full-stack Java EE server, which supports everything on the Java EE spec (servlets, JSPs, EJB, JMS, JPA, JTA, etc.)

Oracle has tutorials on Java EE. Google for them.